# Perform action AFTER subscribing to observable

Tags: android, rx-java

I want to perform an action, which is executed **after** subscribing to an `Observable`. Currently I perform some BLE related operations like reading the rssi of my connection:

```
public class BleGattOperations {

   private class BleGattCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {
       public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
           readRssiSubject.onNext(new RssiState(gatt, rssi, status));
       }
   }

    // Defined in Constructor
    private final BluetoothGattCallback callback;
    // Defined in Constructor
    private BluetoothGatt gatt;
    private final Subject<RssiState, RssiState> readRssiSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    public Observable<RssiState> readRssi() {
        return readRssiSubject
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> {
                 gatt.readRemoteRssi();
            })
            .take(1);
    }
}
```

Within the `readRssi()`-method I subscribe to the `readRssiSubject`, which emits items in the `BleGattCallback.onReadRemoteRssi-Method()`. The read rssi operation on ble side is triggered via the `gatt.readRemoteRssi()` operation inside the `doOnSubscribe()`-block.

Unfortunately the doOnSubscribe-method is executed **before** any subscription to the subject is done and sometimes the read rssi operation is faster executed than the subscription to the `readRssiSubject` is done. Therefore the newly subscribed subscriber does not receive the result of the rssi measurement as the subscription was done, after the `onReadRemoteRssi`-method was executed.

Maybe some experimental code snippet helps to understand what is basically happen:

```
public Observable<RssiState> readRssi() {
    return readRssiSubject
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> {
             readRssiSubject.onNext(new RssiState());
        })
        .take(1);
}
```

Is there a way to perform a action **after** a subscription was done to an Subject/Observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `doOnSubscribe` documentation:

> Each subscription will result in an invocation of the given action *except when the source ObservableSource is reference counted*, in which case the source ObservableSource will invoke the given action **for the first subscription**.

And `PublishSubject` is reference counted.

### Alternative solution

Although you are using `PublishSubject` it does not look like you are going to share messages from it to more than one subscriber. In that case I would recommend the following implemetation of `readRssi()`:

```
public Observable<RssiState> readRssi() {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
             // this is invoked for every new subscriber
             BluetoothGattCallback callback = 
                 (BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) -> {
                     emitter.onNext(new RssiState(gatt, rssi, status));
                     emitter.onComplete();
                 };
             gatt.addListener(callback); // not sure about method name
             gatt.readRemoteRssi(); // initiate read
        });
}
```

See [documentation and example](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#create(io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe)) for `create` method.

Comment: Basically, I have more than one subscriber in my later business logic. Do you think it is a good idea to add methods for register and unregister emitters in the callback? The callback is furthermore used for the whole BLEl connection which makes it hard to create within an Observable.

Comment: @Christopher 1) If other subscribers need to request fresh data from bluetooth, then use it as it is. Otherwise you can cache data with `cache()` or `replay()`. 2) You can use `emitter.setCancellable` to cancel request and unregister listener. 3) You can write listener add/remove methods for your global bluetooth connection.

Comment: I implemented it now using option (2) and (3). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can postpone action until after subscription is done by merging you `Observable` with `Completable` like this:

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> Observable<T>.doAfterSubscribe(action: () -> Unit): Observable<T> {
    return mergeWith(Completable.fromAction(action))
}
```

Here is sequence diagram of how this works:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use concatEager to trigger execution of multiple `Observable`s and keep their emission order:

```
Observable<Data> immediate = ...
Observable<Data> async = ...

Observable.concatEager(immediate, asnyc)
.subscribe();
```

While immediate is running, async's values get buffered until immediate **completes**, then the sequence switches to async. Note that `concatEager` prefetches a limited number of items from a non-current source, that is, if async produces a lot of items while immediate is still active, you'll get a `MissingBackpressureException`.

Comment: I am not sure, that this helps. the problem is that my readRssiSubject emits an item before the subscription was done. How is that solved by your approach? Thank you!